# Not getting output while creating Hash of Arrays

Tags: perl

I am trying to create hash of arrays. I am taking data from a txt file and converting this into hash of arrays.

Txt file data is as below

```
group1 : usr1 usr4 usr6
group2 : usr2 usr1 usr5
group3 : usr1 usr2 usr3
```

so on ......

I am converting this hash of arrays like

```
%hash = (group1 => [usr1 usr4 usr6], group2 => [usr2 usr1 usr5]);
```

Following code i am trying

```
%hash = ();
open (FH, "2.txt") or die "file not found";
while (<FH>) {
@array = split (":", $_);
$array[1] =~ s/^\s*//;
$array[1] =~ s/\s*$//;
@arrayRef = split (" ", $array[1]);
$hash{$array[0]} = [ @arrayRef ];
#print @array;
#print "\n";
}
close FH;


print $hash{group1}[0];
print @{ $hash{group2}};
```

I am not getting output. There is something wrong in the code. Please help me understanding it better

Comment: `split ""` will split on the empty string, which means `usr1` will be split up into `qw(u s r 1)`.

Comment: Oh my mistake.. I corrected but not getting the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me, but the problem is that you are using the key `"group1 "` (note the extra space), and not `"group1"` like you think. When you split on colon `:`, you remember to strip the fields after from spaces, but not the field before. You should probably do:

```
my @array = split /\s*:\s*/, $_;
```

Also, you should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Coding without these two pragmas is difficult and takes much longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
open (my $FH, "<", "2.txt") or die $!;
while (<$FH>) {
  my ($key, @array) = split /[:\s]+/, $_;
  $hash{$key} = \@array;
}
close $FH;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: @Nitesh insted of `$hash{$array[0]} = [ @arrayRef ];` you need `my $key= shift @array;$hash{$key} = \@array;` but since `@array` isn't lexicaly scoped (and it should be) that would be `$hash{$key} = [ @array ];`

Comment: How is it making difference. shift @array will give the last element which is index 1.

Comment: `shift` gives first element of array (array index starts with `0`)

Comment: @mpapec No, his code is correct. The problem is the key is something other than he thinks.